# Data too big in pandas & seaborn. How to create an "other" column?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a series of names each related to an ID.
In pandas I then combined these names so each ID would just have a combination as opposed to many individual names.

Then I created a count to see how many times these combinations would appear.
For example I wanted people who ate apples and oranges.

```
**Combination           Count**
Apples, Oranges         2
Apples                  1
Oranges                 1
```

However, my specific data set was far too large and I have many elements with the count of 1. I am trying to combine these into an "other" group to display using seaborn for a bar chart. However, all the names overlap due the such volume of data. I want to merge probably the last 500 rows of my data set to "other" (as the combination name) and the count is the sum of all those counts.

In this example it would be like this:

```
**Combination           Count**
Apples, Oranges         2
Other                   2
```

I have tried using groupby, but lacking experience in pandas I am unsure of how to write this syntactically. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your issue that you want to merge all "combinations" with "count" 1 into a single "combination" called "Other" with the appropriate count?

Comment: what is you expected out put for above sample data frame

Comment: No I don't want to merge the two columns. I just have far too many rows to display easily. So I want to merge say the bottom 500 rows into an "other" catagory to display in pie charts/bar charts easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have done `import numpy as np`, you can use `np.where()` to generate a new column which uses `'Other'` if the `Count` is 1, or the existing `Combination` otherwise.Then we can `.groupby` and `sum` to find totals on `'New Combination'`. Assuming your frame is called `df`:

```
df['New Combination'] = np.where(df['Count'] == 1, 'Other', df['Combination'])
totals = df.groupby('New Combination').agg({'Count': 'sum'})
```

This gives you:

```
                  Count
New Combination       
Apples, Oranges       2
Other                 2
```